# Continuity of integral whose domain of integration depends continuously on time

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega(t)$ be a region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that depends continuously on some parameter $t$.

Let $f$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f > 0$ almost everywhere.

Then, can we say that the mapping $h$ given by

$$h(t): t \to \int_{\Omega(t)} f(x)dx $$

is continuous?

Comment: how is the continuity of $\Omega$ defined?

Comment: @user251257 The contiunity is defined in the sense that the difference in "area" or "volume" is small: for every $t$, $|\Omega(t_0) - \Omega(t)|$ is small for $t_0$ close enough to $t$

Comment: do you mean $\int |\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)} - \mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)} | \to 0$ for $t\to t_0$?

Comment: is $f$ integrable? if yes, then dominated convergence theorem. otherwise you probably need some assumption on $\Omega$

Comment: @user251257 Yes, that is what I meant. And $f$ is integrable. How do you apply the dominated convergence theorem? Do you mind telling me a bit more in details? I am not so sure why the sequence $f \cdot 1_{\Omega(t)}$ converges to $f \cdot 1_{\Omega(t_0)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}$ converges to $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ in $L_1$,  we have $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}\to \mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ (globally) in measure.

Since $\mathbb R^n$ with the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$ finite,
$f\cdot\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}$ converges to $f\cdot\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ **locally** in measure. 
As $f \cdot |\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)} - \mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}|$ is dominated by $f$, which is integrable, we have by dominated convergence theorem
$$ \lim_{t\to t_0} \int f \cdot |\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)} - \mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}| = 0. $$

**Alternative:**

Define $\mu(A) = \int_A f(x) \; \mathrm d x$. Then, $\mu$ is a **finite** measure and absolutely continuous w.r.t. to the Lebesgue measure. Thus, $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}$ converges to $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}$ (globally) in measure w.r.t. $\mu$. By dominated convergence theorem follows
$$ \lim_{t\to t_0} \int |\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)} - \mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}| \; \mathrm d\mu = 0. $$

Comment: Is there reason why you say $1_{\Omega(t)}\to 1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ in $L^1$ implies LOCAL convergence in measure? What do you mean by local?

Comment: for no reason. I have remembered the theorem wrong. $L_1$ convergence implies global convergence in measure, $\sigma$ finite or not. I will corrected the answer.

Comment: @pm021: I need the local convergence and $\sigma$ finiteness later anyway.

Comment: how does the $\sigma$-finiteness give that the convergence of $1_{\Omega(t)}$ to $1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ in measure imply the local convergence of  $f1_{\Omega(t)}$ to $f1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ in measure?

Comment: what do you mean "how"? By assumption $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}$ converges to $\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ in $L_1$ (That is what I asked you before). $L_p$ convergence implies convergence in measure (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure).

Comment: I understand that $1_{\Omega(t)}$ converges to $1_{\Omega(t_0)}$ in measure. But, I don't understand the part where you say "Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\sigma$-finite, $f 1_{\Omega(t)} \to  f1_{\Omega(t_0)}$locally in measure". my question wasn't worded propery...

Comment: that is also in the wikipedia article. If the space is $\sigma$ finite then product of locally convergent sequences is locally convergent again.

Comment: the wikipedia only says that the product is convergent in measure if the space is finite, not necessarily $\sigma$-finite. So, I wasn wondering about that

Comment: @pm021: oh sorry. The proof is following: In a $\sigma$-finite space, $f_n$ converges to $f$ locally in measure if and only if *every* subsequence $f_{n_m}$ admits a subsequence $f_{n_{m_k}}$ which converges to $f$ a.e. Now, a.e. convergence is preserved by continuous mapping, like multiplication. Notice I add an alternative proof without the product $f\cdot\mathbb 1_{\Omega(t)}$

Comment: I see In your altertative proof, why is the measure $\mu$ finite?

Comment: @pm021: You said, $f$ is integrable, that is $\mu(\mathbb R^n) = \int f(x) \;\mathrm d x < \infty$.

Comment: sorry for asking a lot. I understand that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t to the lebesgue measure, but then why do you have "thus $1_{\Omega(t)} \to 1_{\Omega(t_0}$ globally in measure? Then, you apply the dominated convergence but where did $f$ in the integrand go?

Comment: @pm021: on **finite** measure space, local and global convergence in measure is the same. If $g_n\to g$ in measure w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Then, every subsequence admits a Lebesgue a.e. convergent subsequence. Since $\mu$ is abs. continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, that subsequence also converges $\mu$ a.e. That is, $g_n\to g$ in measure w.r.t. $\mu$. Finally, I used the DCT w.r.t. $\mu$, as $\int g \;\mathrm d\mu = \int g(x)\cdot f(x) \;\mathrm d x$.